# can't return arrayList from method

Tags: java

So I'm teaching myself Java and not that great at it yet, but trying my hand at making a game. I'm trying to return an arraylist from a class method, but it keeps giving me a "int cannot be dereferenced" error.  This is a method from a class called Levels. It should create a list of aliens and return it to the main game. I have a bunch of classes that extend sprite to represent different enemies. So alien# extends sprite.

```
public ArrayList<Sprite> sendWave(){
    aliens = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
    aliens.add(new Alien1(100, 50, difficulty));
    // etc
    return aliens;
}
```

later in the board class which draws everything, I want to read that ArrayList. I've got this currently:

```
public void initAliens() {
    Levels level = new Levels();
    ArrayList<Sprite> aliens = new ArrayList<>();     
    aliens.addAll(level.sendWave()); 
    // blah blah
}
```

I've also tried:

```
aliens = level.sendWave();
```

or even just testing the method alone by doing:

```
level.sendWave();
```

It always gives me that "int cannot be dereferenced" error. I don't really understand what that means. What int? Am I returning the arraylist incorrectly or something?

Comment: Where does the error occur? Show all your code

Comment: That error isn't related to the `ArrayList`. There's a problem with something else in your code.

Comment: StackTrace please...?

Comment: Somewhere down the line ,you are calling any method on primitive (int) which you should be calling on Integer ,I guess

Comment: StackTrace is your best friend. Get to know it well, it'll help you a lot.

Comment: We can help you if you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. There is nothing in the code you have posted so far that might explain the error message that you quote.

Comment: Maybe some issue with the Alien1 constructor?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem if I build the arraylist outside of the levels class. It's only when I try to access the method. The method always causes an error and won't compile at all.

Comment: Then add the full Levels class code here. And compiler errors still tell you where in the code they occur; we need that as well if we're to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an `int level;`.

The general pattern is:

```
public List<Sprite> sendWave() {
    List<Sprite> aliens = new ArrayList<>();
    aliens.add(new Alien1(100, 50, difficulty));
    // etc
    return aliens;
}

List<Sprite> aliens = sendWave();
aliens.addAll(sendWave);
```

or

```
public void sendWave(List<Sprite> aliens) {
    aliens.add(new Alien1(100, 50, difficulty));
    // etc
}

List<Sprite> aliens = new ArrayList<>();
sendWave(aliens);
sendWave(aliens);
```

You did have a usage of `aliens` defined outside the method, hence some field. Above there is a local independant variable `aliens` not interfering with any whatsoever named field.

Maybe thas was an `int aliens`.

Better is to use local variables, as close as possible to their usage.

Above I also use a more general `List<Sprite>` - an interface List actually. And I create an instance using an *implementation* class, `ArrayList`.

Java has many interfaces like `List`, `Map` and `Set` and allows specialized implementation classes like `LinkedList`, `HashMap` and `TreeSet`.

Using the above extra care, one change the implementation in the future without many code changes. It is in fact a language feature, being able to provide the best implementation for some use-case, that some scripting language do not have.

For the rest I did not see any problem in your code, probably fields interfering.

Comment: Yeah, I did that before, and was wondering if some sort of type thing was an issue so changed it all to ArrayList. The error always happens when I try to use sendWave() though.

Comment: What does your `Alien1` class look like?  Can you add that to your post?

Comment: Rename the method, maybe there lingers an other sendWave around. Do a clean build. Check what classes are used

Comment: Doh! I think I might have figured out the problem. I have a level that is assigned as an int. That is what was giving me that issue. It's compiling now. Still giving me an error, but a DIFFERENT error is progress, right?

Comment: Developers ever more gain higher levels of errors, I believe.